Is this a valid use case for eval or how could I avoid security risks?
I solved this Hackerrank challenge using the match statement introduced with Python 3.10. I used eval to dynamically execute the command given in the input.
However, I'm aware that execute code dynamically could lead to security risks. I already read this old discussion about the topic: Why is using 'eval' a bad practice? so I'm wondering if there's an alternative way to use it or this could be a valid use case for eval.
I really don't like statements such as "always avoid this" because we have those commands for using it and if we should always avoid it, then why they're not just removed? For me, it's better to understand the risks and know how to avoid them and give examples of valid use cases and alternatives when there're not valid uses cases.
For me, the code below is a valid use case, but I'd appreciate other opinions and if you think that there is a real risk. I'm most a Ruby developer, so I still not know all the nuances of Python.
def call_fun(i_lst):
    args_num = len(i_lst)
    
     
    match args_num:
        case 1:
            if i_lst[0] == "print":
                eval(i_lst[0] + "(o_list)")
            else:
                eval("o_list.{}()".format(*i_lst))
        case 2:
            eval("o_list.{}({})".format(*i_lst))
        case 3:
            eval("o_list.{}({},{})".format(*i_lst))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
    o_list = []
    
    for x in range(N):
        command = input().split()
        call_fun(command)

I know that I will receive strings that match with list methods (append, insert, sort, etc.) and a print statement. That methods and their arguments are my input list (i_lst).
I think that this is a valid use case for eval, as eval only can execute a single expression, and I'm attaching to commands for lists, so if a malicious code is intended in the input, it would raise a Syntax error. I tried in my interpreter this case to be sure:
a_lst = ["append", "5); print('Unsafe'"]
So, if I could introduce malicious code, I could execute append and then whatever malicious code. However, when I run it with eval, it gives me the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in call_fun
  File "<string>", line 1
    o_lst.append(5); print('Unsafe')
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

For that reason, I'm inclined to think it's a safe implementation.
I read the recommendation to use globals and locals to limit security risks with eval, but not sure how to implement that, and if in this case, it would be a nice to have.
Is there any other case that could be a security risk that I'm missing, so it would be better to avoid 'eval'? Or do you also think this is a safe and valid use case?

Python doesn't have a switch statement, it has a match statement (added in 3.10, not 3.11). There's a huge difference. Match is used for pattern matching and is way more powerful, than switch. Additionally, switch is much faster than if-statements, while python's match is sometimes slower.

You can store the methods to look them up by name in your own mapping; or you can use the more specific functionality to access a method (since it's an attribute) of the list by name. Please see the linked duplicates.


Is this a valid use case for eval

As a rule, no. Pretend it doesn’t exist and you’ll end up with cleaner, safer solutions:
def call_fun(cmd):
    match cmd:
        case ["print"]:
            print(o_list)
        case ["sort"]:
            o_list.sort()
        case ["pop"]:
            o_list.pop()
        case ["reverse"]:
            o_list.reverse()
        case ["remove", value]:
            o_list.remove(int(value))
        case ["append", value]:
            o_list.append(int(value))
        case ["insert", index, value]:
            o_list.insert(int(index), int(value))
        case _:
            raise ValueError("invalid command")

Or if you insist on making use of the dynamic language features,
def call_fun(cmd):
    match cmd:
        case ["print"]:
            print(o_list)
        case [("sort" | "pop" | "reverse" | "remove" | "append" | "insert") as method, *args]:
            getattr(o_list, method)(*map(int, args))
        case _:
            raise ValueError("invalid command")

Another variation:
METHODS = {
    "sort": list.sort,
    "pop": list.pop,
    "reverse": list.reverse,
    "remove": list.remove,
    "append": list.append,
    "insert": list.insert,
}  # or {k: getattr(list, k) for k in […]}


def call_fun(cmd):
    if cmd == ["print"]:
        print(o_list)
    elif cmd and cmd[0] in METHODS:
        METHODS[cmd[0]](o_list, *map(int, cmd[1:]))
    else:
        raise ValueError("invalid command")

And yes, your code is vulnerable if malicious input is in the cards – to arbitrary code execution (lots of examples on how to exploit eval online that apply), but also just to things like:
append open("/etc/passwd").read()



if a malicious code is intended in the input, it would raise a Syntax error.

It is quite possible to design malicious code that will be executed with your program. Consider this input (first line is N):
1
append __import__('os').remove('test.txt')

The expression that your code will evaluate is:
o_list.append(__import__('os').remove('test.txt'))

...and it will delete the file 'test.txt' if it exists.
Same principle, but without arguments:
1
count(__import__('os').remove('test.txt')).__str__

What is evaluated:
o_list.count(__import__('os').remove('test.txt')).__str__()

So, yes, others are right: if what you evaluate originates (partly) from user input, you should be alerted and take precautions. Most of the time there are better, safer solutions, as also here.
For instance, you could do something dynamic using getattr and verifying the function to be called is a key in a dict and the corresponding value is the number of arguments provided:
allowed = {
    "insert": 2,
    "print": 0,
    "remove": 1,
    "append": 1,
    "sort": 0,
    "pop": 0,
    "reverse": 0
}

def call_fun(command):
    func, *args = command
    if allowed.get(func, -1) != len(args):
        raise ValueError("Invalid command")
    if func == "print":
        print(o_list)
    else:
        getattr(o_list, func)(*map(int, args))

